# istioctl command not found in windows 10

Tags: windows, istio

[image]istioctl command not found in windows 10 even though i have added the path

'C:\Users\NSPC\Documents\istio\istio-1.1.8\bin' in environment variables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you verify the PATH value with  "echo $env:PATH" command?

Comment: Your file has no executable extension so will not run as such.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to https://github.com/istio/istio/releases and under Istio version download *.zip version for windows (if is not visible expand "Assets"). Currently it is Istio 1.1.9 and name of the file is istio-1.1.9-win.zip
2. Unpack this file.
3. Go to `istioctl.exe` (i.e *C:\Users\%USERNAME%\istio-1.1.9-win\bin*). Make sure in bin directory is executable file. If its not there, you should download different version.
4. Search "*Edit environment variables for your account*"
5. Click on the "Path" variable and then use "Edit...". **You cannot create new Path variable, you must edit already existed.**
6. Click on "New" and paste path to exe file: *C:\Users\%USERNAME%\istio-1.1.9-win\bin*
7. In command prompt check Istio version `$ istioctl version`